# One LVM for multiple nodes in cluster

Tags: lvm, proxmox

We have a cluster with 3 nodes.
On one node hard disks have been added and configured as LVM.
The idea is to make this LVM also available on the other nodes.
Therefore, the other nodes were added to the LVM in the cluster administration and the checkboxes for "Activate" and "Distribute" were set.
The LVM is now also displayed under the other nodes, but with a question mark.
If you go there to the overview, it says "Yes" for Enabled and "No" for Active.
Which settings are still missing for access?
Can someone give me a hint?